# axios CancelToken not functioning, React project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

I have been trying to use axios CancelToken with react. But the cancel token has no effect whatsoever.
A brief about the code:
There is an input, and in the onChange event of the input fires the getData() function.
I want this to NOT send out an api request everytime the user presses the keys but only at the end or maybe after a timeout.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Home() {
    let axiosCancelToken;

    async function getData() {
        if (axiosCancelToken) {
            axiosCancelToken.cancel();
            console.warn('request cancelled')
        }
        console.info('no cancel', axiosCancelToken)
        axiosCancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();

        let val = await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
            cancelToken: axiosCancelToken.token
        })
    }
...
```

And the <input.../>

```
 <input type="text" onChange={getData} />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it doesn't work because you are trying to cancel the wrong token.

Let's look at this example:

```
export default function Home() {
  let axiosCancelToken;

  async function getData() {
    if (axiosCancelToken) {
      axiosCancelToken.cancel();
    }

    axiosCancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();

    let val = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
      cancelToken: axiosCancelToken.token
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getData}>Get Data</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit cool-tdd-5eggnt]

Try clicking the button twice quickly, you will see the first request canceled as expected.

But if I change the code by adding some React state, it won't work anymore:

```
export default function App() {
  let axiosCancelToken;
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  async function getData() {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);

    if (axiosCancelToken) {
      axiosCancelToken.cancel();
      console.warn("request cancelled");
    }

    axiosCancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();

    let val = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
      cancelToken: axiosCancelToken.token
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getData}>Get Data {count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit cocky-dijkstra-hbbxlk]

And the reason for that is that when React has to re-render, it will call your function component again, where your `axiosCancelToken` will be instantiated again in the new scope.

To solve this you can just use React Refs.

```
let axiosCancelToken = useRef();
```

[image: Edit determined-leftpad-fcr5rc]

Comment: This works. Thank you for explaining everything so clearly. I even followed several tutorials but none of them explained what is going on and none of them were using refs.